# rake db:migrate aborted! on US-ASCII using rake 0.9.2.2 and rails 3.0.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, capistrano

Recently I upgraded my gems and started adding new stuff to my app like authentication by third party social websites using omniauth gem. On development environment everything is fine and works like a charm.

I am deploying to staging and production servers using capistrano. Basic deployment is fine and working so far, but I have got really strange problems when I want to do migrations when deploying.

I get the following error messages from capistrano:

```
    [my.server.com] executing command
*** [err :: my.server.com] rake aborted!
*** [err :: my.server.com] "\xC5" on US-ASCII
*** [err :: my.server.com] 
*** [err :: my.server.com] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    command finished in 2472ms
```

I was googling all around and couldn't find any relevant solution. I also tried to downgrade rake gem back to 0.8.7 but with no success on the end - the same errors.

Comment: You using Ruby 1.9.x on the server you're deploying to, and 1.8.x on your development server?

Comment: You might want to try rake v 0.9.2 instead of 0.9.2.2

Comment: Also, Is capistrano running rake db:migrate using bundle exec?

Comment: @smaty no, both are ruby 1.9.2 used via rvm.

Comment: @house9 I have already tried go back to rake 0.8.7 but with no success, before it was working without any problems. And yes, Capistrano is running db:migrate using bundle exec.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix Ruby script which fails with encoding error: "\xD8" on US-ASCII?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464023/how-to-fix-ruby-script-which-fails-with-encoding-error-xd8-on-us-ascii)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of googling and digging in I found the solution that (I hope) may by helpful for someone with a similar or the same problem.

I did `bundle exec rake --trace db:migrate` on the staging server and got the following error messages:

```
rake aborted!
"\xC5" on US-ASCII
/var/www/myapp/test.myapp.com/releases/20111230233802/config/application.rb:5:in `read'
/var/www/myapp/test.myapp.com/releases/20111230233802/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/myapp/test.myapp.com/releases/20111230233802/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/var/www/myapp/test.myapp.com/releases/20111230233802/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/myapp/test.myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/var/www/myapp/test.myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/var/www/myapp/test.myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/var/www/myapp/test.myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/var/www/myapp/test.myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/www/myapp/test.myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/var/www/myapp/test.myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/var/www/myapp/test.myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/www/myapp/test.myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/var/www/myapp/test.myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/myapp/test.myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/var/www/myapp/test.myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

So I jumped in to the `config/application.rb` file to find out what could rise the error. Line 5 of that file loads an external config file:

```
require 'yaml'
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../app_config.yml', __FILE__)))
```

and that external file contains UTF-8 chars, not US-ASCII. So I tried a couple of different solutions to solve that problem.

The only one which worked for me was to add an extra few lines of code on top of `config/application.rb` file:

```
if RUBY_VERSION =~ /1.9/
  Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
  Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
end
```

just to tell rake to load external files using utf-8 encoding. After that change everything went smooth and exactly as expected. Problem solved!

PS.
I really don't know why developers of rake 0.9 have changed previous behavior of rake 0.8 which worked fine for me and probably for you as well for a long time. Maybe you have an idea why? I am very curious.