# How to fix Ruby script which fails with encoding error: "\xD8" on US-ASCII?

Tags: ruby, jenkins, character-encoding, cucumber, hudson

I get the following error when running a project with:

```
cucumber --format junit --guess --out ./
```

This is the error:

```
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/hudson/jobs/PersOC-CucumberTests/workspace -      hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@3b815cce
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision 3dc11ccba9c86308b422d6261ecde95d0a4ae999 (origin/master)
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/hudson/jobs/CucumberTests/workspace -   hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@3b815cce
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from /srv/git/cucumber.git
Commencing build of Revision 14627f9a6682b82a9b4d64172278a646da358c24 (origin/master)
Checking out Revision 14627f9a6682b82a9b4d64172278a646da358c24 (origin/master)
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson6604637626131848657.sh
+ cucumber --format junit --guess --out ./
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `encode': "\xD8"  on US-ASCII (Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError)
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `initialize'
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `new'
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gherkin-2.11.2/lib/gherkin/i18n.rb:14:in `<class:I18n>'
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gherkin-2.11.2/lib/gherkin/i18n.rb:6:in `<module:Gherkin>'
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gherkin-2.11.2/lib/gherkin/i18n.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'

[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build: CucumberTests #168 due to result: FAILURE 
Finished: FAILURE
```

Every single file in this project is marked with:

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

What can I try?

Comment: Please post the output of `locale -a` and `locale` (as the user hudson is running under)

Comment: locale
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: (hab mal alles bis auf DE und eng rausgenommen, weil zuviele zeichen) locale -a
de_AT
de_AT@euro
de_AT.utf8
de_BE
de_BE@euro
de_BE.utf8
de_CH
de_CH.utf8
de_DE
de_DE@euro
de_DE.utf8
de_LU
de_LU@euro
de_LU.utf8
dv_MV
dz_BT
el_CY
el_CY.utf8
el_GR
el_GR.utf8
en_AG
en_AU
en_AU.utf8
en_BE
en_BE@euro
en_BE.utf8
en_BW
en_BW.utf8
en_CA
en_CA.utf8
en_DK
en_DK.utf8
en_GB
en_GB.iso885915
en_GB.utf8
en_HK
en_HK.utf8
en_IE
en_IE@euro
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_NG
en_NZ
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH
en_PH.utf8
en_SG
en_SG.utf8
en_US
en_US.iso885915
en_US.utf8
en_ZA
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZW
en_ZW.utf8

Comment: it runs with ruby 1.8.7, but I need ruby 1.9 for a redmine plugin, what can I do?

Comment: Not sure. The error is usually caused by having incorrect locale settings in the console you run your tests from. If you're sure you switched to your hudson user, ran /bin/sh and still got the locale output you posted above, I have no idea.

Comment: did check /bin/sh locale with user hudson and got same result :(

Answer (score 2):

There are issues with your environments LC encodings.

### Linux

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

### OS X (pre Mnt. Lion)

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

### OS X (Mnt. Lion and later)

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, only on my test CI server.  Same code, same LANG and everything works fine on my local linux server.  Tried the export, also tried the "localedef -v -c -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8" listed here on the cucumber issue: https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin/issues/192  Anyone have any idea why it would still be throwing an error?

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be also fixed in Ruby code it-self, by adding the following code:

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

Comment: This is a pretty solid answer, thanks